# No result when use "button" and innerHTML in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I make a button that once click will show "Hello World", But it does not work. I don't know where I made mistakes.

This is button an div.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction():"> Click me to see the result</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

This is my script.

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the onclick handler. Read the browser console / error log.

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag because there is no jQuery in the posted code.

Comment: This question is just about a typo, as can be seen from the comments and the only answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon should be removed from "myFunction()".

Comment: Oh, yes. Just found it. Thank you!